# How to scroll to an element from a modal submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, bootstrap-modal

I would like my **modal's submit button** to bring my users **to my contact form** outside of the modal and to close the modal in the process.
I've tried several ideas but so far, I am scrolling to the element wanted but when the modal closes it scrolls back to the element where my modal is initially located.

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal-<?= $formation['id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?= $formation['descriptionLongue'] ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary devis">Demander un devis</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <!-- FORMATION -->
```

Contact Form

```
   <div class="container col-4" id="contact">
<!-- form contact -->
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5" action="<?=buildUrl('/contact');?>" method="POST">
    
etc...
```

Javacript

```
const target = document.getElementById('contact'),
      buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.devis');
      
      for (const button of buttons) {
button.addEventListener('click', function(){


    $(this).parents('.modal').modal('hide');
    target.scrollIntoView({
        block: 'start',
        behavior: 'smooth',
        inline: 'nearest'
   
    });
    
});
}
```